# Angular CLI prod build mangles Font Awesome icons

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My Angular 7 application has some font awesome icons that are partially mangled when running a production build, it seems fine in dev mode. Error is:

> attribute d: Expected number, "…
>   158-141.6h-108c-***************…".

I import FontAwesome using the following code in my angular.json file:

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/font-awesome.js"
            ]
]
```

Can anyone help as to why this error occurs?

Example

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use D3.js in your project?

Comment: No, FontAwesome via a JS import

Answer (score 0):

This is the official font awesome angular library, you should use this:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#upgrading-font-awesome

Comment: I got the same result using that method. In fact, its mangled more of them. Thanks though